# add a payment fee when using PayPal using Magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento, paypal

I am a about to start a very small webshop using magento.
I would like to charge a small payment fee for using PayPal, I've tried multiple plugins but none of them were accepted by paypal.

Any solutions out there?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a vendor Policy matter. On that note, stop looking for a "solution" because you **can't** based on [Paypal TOS specifically see **4.5**](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full)

Comment: `"4.5 No Surcharges. You agree that you will not impose a surcharge or any other fee for accepting PayPal as a payment method. You may charge a handling fee in connection with the sale of goods or services as long as the handling fee does not operate as a surcharge and is not higher than the handling fee you charge for non-PayPal transactions."`

Answer (score 0):

You can charge customer fee with this free Magento extension, This is the reference link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-payment-fee.html

Comment: Hmm... unless I missed it wouldn't that go against Paypal policy?